# Explanation of possible implementation of std::is_base_of

Tags: c++, c++11

```
1.  template <typename Base> std::true_type is_base_of_test_func( Base* );
2.  template <typename Base> std::false_type is_base_of_test_func( void* );
3.  template <typename Base, typename Derived>
    using pre_is_base_of = decltype( is_base_of_test_func<Base>( std::declval<Derived*>() ) );

4.  template <typename Base, typename Derived, typename = void>
    struct pre_is_base_of2 : public std::true_type {};

5.  template<typename ...> using void_t = void;
6.  template <typename Base, typename Derived>
    struct pre_is_base_of2<Base, Derived, void_t<pre_is_base_of<Base, Derived>>> : public pre_is_base_of<Base, Derived>{};


7.  template <typename Base, typename Derived>
    struct is_base_of : public std::conditional_t<std::is_class<Base>::value && std::is_class<Derived>::value,
                                                  pre_is_base_of2<Base, Derived>,
                                                  std::false_type>
    {
    };
```

Lines 1. and 2. are pretty much straight forward. <del>But, line 3: the `using` there is extremely vague, because I cannot simply replace every occurrence of `pre_is_base_of` with its definition. Ergo, the `using` is not really what the documentation says. It involves some religion as well.</del> If I'm not wrong, the usage of `pre_is_base_of` should return `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`.
 I'm equally lost when it comes to `void_t`. What kind of magic will that line do?
Shouldn't both implementations of `pre_is_base_of2` take 3 types? What's the point of inheritance in line 6?  There is probably more, but lets stop now.

I would need some detailed explanation on magic involved here. Basically I'm trying to understand how that code works.

Edit: When [default](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238902/default) asked me what's the error, I replaced every occurrence of `pre_is_base_of` and now there is no error.

Comment: "I cannot simply replace every occurrence of `pre_is_base_of` with its definition" Why?

Comment: @cpplearner the compiler doesn't like it. It throws an error.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: what documentation did you read?

Comment: what do you mean by religion?

Comment: I believe that this implementation of `is_base_of` is copied from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of. The author of that implementation gave a bit of explanation in [the corresponding talk page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: @cpplearner, yes it is probably copied from that URL. But, I don't see any detailed explanation on how it works.

Comment: @MalikUrac, it is not particularly detailed, but it does explain it, as long as you understand specializations correctly (that bit is rather non-obvious).

Comment: @Jan, why don't you explain the main catch? Your comment could be valid, but it's not helpful at all.

Comment: @MalikUrac, I didn't get around to it yet. The catch is that the default arguments are completed according to the declaration, then the specializations are evaluated and applied *if* they are valid and match. So you get line 6 if `pre_is_base_of` can be substituted, which is and line 4 if it does not, which is exactly when Base is an inaccessible base of Derived.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. `template <typename Base> std::true_type is_base_of_test_func( Base* );`

When the argument is a Base, or derived from Base, this overload has the highest priority

> 2. `template <typename Base> std::false_type is_base_of_test_func( void* );`

this overload will match any type, with the lowest priority

> 3. `template <typename Base, typename Derived>
>      using pre_is_base_of = decltype( is_base_of_test_func<Base>( std::declval<Derived*>() ) );`

pre_is_base_of will become the type returned by calling `is_base_of_test_func` with a pointer to `Derived`. If `Derived` is derived from Base, it will return std::true_type, otherwise the void* overload will be selected and it will return a std::false_type. Now we have converted a function call result into a type.

> 4. `template <typename Base, typename Derived, typename = void>
>      struct pre_is_base_of2 : public std::true_type {};`

General case, this will be a true_type. Since the 3rd template argument is defaulted, this will be the version of the class defined when no other specialisation is created.

> 5. `template<typename ...> using void_t = void;`

This is an easier way of doing enable_if. `void_t<X>` will only be a type if X is a legal type.

> 6. `template <typename Base, typename Derived>
>      struct pre_is_base_of2<Base, Derived, void_t<pre_is_base_of<Base, Derived>>> : public pre_is_base_of<Base, Derived>{};`

if `void_t` is a legal type (i.e. `pre_is_base_of<Base>(Derived*)` is a valid expression, this will be the specialisation of `pre_is_base_of2`, which will evaluate to the decltype of calling the test function, above. It will only be selected if `pre_is_base_of<Base,Derived>` is a valid type (i.e. there exists a call to the test function)

> 7. `template <typename Base, typename Derived>
>      struct is_base_of : public std::conditional_t<std::is_class<Base>::value && std::is_class<Derived>::value,
>                                                    pre_is_base_of2<Base, Derived>,
>                                                    std::false_type>
>      {
>      };`

essentially this is saying:

```
IF Base and Value are classes AND void_t<decltype(is_base_of_test_func<Base>(Derived*))> is a type
THEN
    select the type of pre_is_base_of2<Base, Derived, void_t<...is the expression legal?...>>
ELSE
    select false_type
```

Update:

Hopefully this little demo program will provide some clarity:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class...> using void_t = void;

// this expands in any case where no second type is provided
template<class T, typename = void> struct does_he_take_sugar : std::false_type {};

// the specialisation can only be valid when void_t<expr> evaluates to a type.
// i.e. when T has a member function called take_sugar
template<class T> struct does_he_take_sugar<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().take_sugar())>> : std::true_type {};


struct X {
    int take_sugar();
};

struct Y {
    int does_not();
};

int main()
{

    // X::take_sugar is a function therefore void_t<decltype(...X)> will evaluate to void
    std::cout << does_he_take_sugar<X>::value << std::endl;

    // Y::take_sugar is not a function therefore void_t<decltype(...Y)> will not evaluate at all
    std::cout << does_he_take_sugar<Y>::value << std::endl;

    // int::take_sugar is not even valid c++ void_t<decltype(...int)> will not evaluate at all
    std::cout << does_he_take_sugar<int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you clarified some things, thank you. Regarding 6. If `void_t` is not a valid type, what type will be returned? What specialization will handle  that?

Comment: @MalikUrac none. the specialisation will fail through SFNIE

Comment: let me rephrase it.. What code is handling that substitution failure? It is still not clear to me how can we have `pre_is_base_of2` with 2 and with 3 template args? The third one has a default type `void`. What is happening if `void_t` returns `int`?

Comment: @MalikUrac `void_t<X...>` will always resolve to the pseudo-type `void`, or it will not resolve at all (error case). If it does not resolve at all, then whatever template expansion that depends on it will not happen (SFNAE). 
In the expression `MyTemplate<void_t<X>>`, if `void_t<X>` is invalid, there is no expansion. If there is a default available e.g., `template class MyTemplate<typename = void>{};`, then this one will be used instead.

Comment: @MalikUrac added a little demo which will hopefully help you to understand how specialisations get selected

Comment: `will not evaluate at all` is the part that was killing me. Thank you!

Comment: still, one thing is contradictory to me: `X::take_sugar is a function therefore void_t<decltype(...X)> will evaluate to void`?? Shouldn't that evaluate to `int`? If it evaluates to `void`, then it failed and there is no `take_shugar()` member function available. Or am I missing the point as hard as possible....

Comment: @MalikUrac `decltype(...X)` will evaluate to `int`, but `void_t<int>` will evaluate to void. Therefore `void_t<decltype(...X)>` will evaluate to `void`. The point of the exercise is not to find the method's return type, but to see whether the return type exists at all. We want to do this without causing a compiler error. the deduction of `void_t` causes the evaluation of the return type to take place in a non-executed context, which means it won't cause a compiler error if it fails - merely a refusal to create a type.

Comment: If we look at the code marked with `4.`, isn't `: public std::true_type` part completely unnecessary? `void_t` will ALWAYS return void and we have necessary inheritance in `6.`

Comment: @MalikUrac i think it's overly-complicated too, but it may have been written with old or non-conforming (e.g. microsoft's lack of 2-phase lookup) in mind.

Answer (score 0):

A skeleton for a possible implementation. In the current form, it does not take into account the POD types.

```
template <class Base, class Derived, class = void>
struct is_base_of
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <class Base, class Derived>
struct is_base_of<Base, Derived, typename enable_if<(Base*)(Derived*)nullptr == (Derived*)nullptr, void>::type>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

This comparison does the trick: `(Base*)(Derived*)nullptr == (Derived*)nullptr`. The comparison is valid only when `Derived` inherits from `Base`, otherwise the expression is not valid and it leads to SFINAE.

Comment: It's also valid if Base inherits from Derived, which is probably not what was intended.

Comment: @N. Shead thanks. I have added a fix for the case 'Base inherits Derived'.